# How to define URL of Ocelot API Gateway

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, ocelot

I have three ASP.NET Core WebAPI services Customer, Subscribe, Unscubscribe with swashbuckle and  docker compose project
All is working well
I have added Ocelot API Gateway (ASP.NET core Project) with Ocelot installed.

Access customer service via own address *https:///api/Customer* works great. But from gateway I don't know which url should I use for example this customer service
I have tried many variants like:

- http:///api/
- http:///api/a/customer
- http:///a/api/customer

but all of them returns 404. 
*May be problem with that Gateway is http not https?*

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

            builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton(builder))
                                                          .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                              ic => ic.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine("configuration",
                                                                "configuration.json")))
                                                                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            var host = builder.Build();
            return host;
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Configurations:

configuration.json:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamPort": 80,
      "DownstreamHost": "customer.api",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/a/",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamPort": 80,
      "DownstreamHost": "customer.api",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/a/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamPort": 80,
      "DownstreamHost": "subscribe.api",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/b/",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamPort": 80,
      "DownstreamHost": "subscribe.api",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/b/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamPort": 80,
      "DownstreamHost": "unsubscribe.api",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/c/",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamPort": 80,
      "DownstreamHost": "unsubscribe.api",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/c/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {}
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  customer.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}customer.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Customer.API\Dockerfile
  subscribe.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}subscribe.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NewsSubscibe.API\Dockerfile
  unsubscribe.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}unsubscribe.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NewsUnSubscribe.API\Dockerfile
  gateway:
    image: gateway
    build:
      context: ./OcelotAPIGateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - customer.api
      - subscribe.api
      - unsubscribe.api
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `UseOcelot().Wait();` in Configure method of Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseOcelot().Wait();
}
```